# Given $y=x+\sqrt{1-x^2}$, express $x$ in terms of $y$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $y=x+\sqrt{1-x^2}$, express $x$ in terms of $y$.

I made up this question, and found it to be surprisingly subtle.

$y-x=\sqrt{1-x^2}$

Square both sides, realizing that this may introduce extraneous solutions.

$y^2-2xy+x^2=1-x^2$

Express as a quadratic in $x$ and solve for $x$.

$2x^2-2yx+y^2-1=0$

$x=\frac{y\pm\sqrt{2-y^2}}{2}$

But this equation has extraneous solutions, for example $(0,1)$.

Neither $x=\frac{y+\sqrt{2-y^2}}{2}$ nor $x=\frac{y-\sqrt{2-y^2}}{2}$ is equivalent to the original equation, as the graphs of these equations show.

By sketching graphs of these equations (which takes a bit of working, if done without a computer or calculator), I have worked out that the answer is:
$$x=\frac{y+\sqrt{2-y^2}}{2},\text{ }y\geq1$$
$$\text{and}$$
$$x=\frac{y-\sqrt{2-y^2}}{2},\text{ }y\geq-1$$

I'm looking for a simpler and/or more rigorous approach (compared to the graphical approach).

Comment: Look where what's under the sqrt becomes 0 in each version of the equation: you get the points (-1, -1), (1/√2, √2), and (1,1). Each segment of your curve ought to both start and end at one of those points. And in case you didn't notice, what you have here is an ellipse — or at least the part of one above the line y=x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A problem is your function is not injective, so it fails to have an inverse, so you have to break it apart at its turning point(s). You can find them by looking for when the derivative is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an approach without derivatives, note that each $x \in [-1,1]$ can be written as $x = \sin t$ for a unique $t \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, and then $\sqrt{1-x^2}=\cos t$. (It's not $\sqrt{1-x^2}=-\cos t$, since both sides must have the same sign). So you get
$$
y = x + \sqrt{1-x^2}
= \sin t + \cos t
= \sqrt2 \sin\bigl( t + \tfrac{\pi}{4} \bigr)
,
$$
from which you see that $y$ increases from $-1$ to $\sqrt2$ as $t$ runs from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/4$, and then decreases back to $1$ as $t$ continues up to $\pi/2$. So for each $y \in [-1,1)$ there is a unique $t$, but for $y \in [1,\sqrt2]$ there are two values of $t$. You can solve for these $t$-values in terms of $y$ from the equation above, and this determines $x=\sin t$ too.